# FullCalendar Cannot read property '_id' of null

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm working with the latest version of FullCalendar (http://fullcalendar.io). FullCalendar displays a calendar plotting customer visit times. It stores calendar events internally to make it faster to go backward and forward to various months. It is working for the current month, the previous month, and on and on until I go back to February 2017, at which time I get the following error message in the JavaScript console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of null
    at buildEventFromInput (fullcalendar.js:13527)
    at fullcalendar.js:12980
    at Object.success (fullcalendar.js:13110)
    at i (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
```

The error appears to fire *before* the AJAX function that obtains the date information, but just to be sure I ran the query for that month, and the data looks fine. Once the error fires, if I go back to one of the months I've already viewed, I don't see the events anymore. The error message is apparently fouling that internal data storage somehow, although the JavaScript is still running or else I wouldn't be able to switch months anymore.

I'm hoping someone who is familiar with FullCalendar has seen this error before can point me in the right direction. The application is protected by a login and contains real client information, so constructing a mock-up for testing purposes will be pretty involved, so I'm hopig nnot to have to burn an hour or two doing that - but if no obvious answers present themselves I'll bite the bullet and do it.

THANKS for any help!

EDIT: Here's a test case.

http://scripturemenu.com/test/index.html

The error message is slightly different from what I reported above (it's trying to read property "hasTime" instead of property "_id" of undefined) - that happened when I switched out the real client names with the words "CLIENT NAME" and an ID, but it still occurs when you hit February.

Interestingly, when I was working with the code to get this test case working, the AJAX call was triggered on January as well, even though after I passed February no dates display on the calendar.

Comment: without seeing your calendar setup and some sample data, it's really impossible to say what the problem is. A full mock-up isn't necessary I don't think, but it would be useful to see the data which causes the error - if it's erroring when doing the ajax call for a specific time period, I'd guess there's probably something missing in the input data - maybe a null object which ought to have a property of "_id".

Comment: And what exactly did you mean by " It stores calendar events internally to make it faster to go backward and forward to various months". Are you having fullCalendar load all the event data up front for a large period of time? Does the error occur at the point where it needs to load more data than was provided up front? Or should there still be data pre-loaded for that month?

Comment: FullCalendar stores the event data as you view months worth of information - I haven't dug into the source code enough to know how it works, but I may have to go there eventually. I don't know if it uses global JavaScript variables, data attributes, or what. You don't reload the page to change months, so it is available without another AJAX round-trip

Comment: "You don't reload the page to change months, so it is available without another AJAX round-trip" Huh? The whole point of AJAX is that you don't have to reload the page. fullCalendar's normal mode of operation is that it makes a new ajax request when you change either the date range, or the view. It will cache data to some extent to minimise the number of trips. If you're saying it _doesn't_ make an ajax request to load more data when you change months then either a) you loaded several months data up front by another method, or b) you loaded static events via an array.

Comment: Again really the fastest way to get some practical help on this will be to show your calendar setup, including how you load events into it, and also some sample data, especially data around the problem data range.

Comment: The caching is what I'm referring to - I didn't think to use the word "caching" to describe it. I haven't done anything funny in the way I use it; it's pretty "from the documentation examples" stuff. I'm not monkeying with the default behavior in any way.

I'll try and get something mocked up today that resembles as closely as possible the real setup, but it can't be the real data - it is customer name, address, etc. and besides it being personal info, I'm under an NDA. I will have to fictionalize it.

Comment: That's no problem. The start/end dates, and anything that has a property `_id` (as per the error) would be the vital bits. The event titles etc can be invented for this purpose. And clearly the calendar setup, and any related code (such as the function buildEventFromInput where the error occurs)

Comment: Test case link added to original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an object without `id` in your february data. You can see it here: 
http://scripturemenu.com/test/calendar-events-json.html?TechID=all&show=customer&start=2017-01-29&end=2017-03-05&_=1502766053928

[image]

That could be the cause of your js error

Comment: This was it! Or, at least it set me on the right track. The problem wound up being in my back-end script - I was creating the JSON objects by concatenating strings and some of the customer names had apostrophes in them ("O'Rourke", etc.) which were fouling things up. Once I resolved that, things started working great!

Comment: I don't know what back-end language you're using but chances are there is a better way to create JSON that just joining strings up, which as you've found, is prone to unexpected error. Usually there's some sort of serialiser tool which exists for the language, and will take care of all that kind of stuff for you. e.g. for PHP there is the "json_encode()" method. Is that the way you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

There's one piece of invalid event data present. Most of the events look correct, with and ID, start and end times, e.g.:

```
{"id":43969,"start":"2017-02-07","title":"CLIENT NAME 43969"}
```

But there's one which does not have any of these properties:

```
{"title":"CLIENT NAME "}
```

Consequently, fullCalendar does not know how to add it to the calendar, and therefore crashes.

This data was retrieved when changing the month view to February, which triggered an AJAX request to

```
http://scripturemenu.com/test/calendar-events-json.html?TechID=all&show=customer&start=2017-01-29&end=2017-03-05&_=1502777909174
```

You need to correct your source data, and/or the code which translates the source data into fullCalendar's JSON format.

Comment: Your answer is more detailed, but since @jperelli answered first I checked his answer. Thanks to both of you for your help!